# Multiprocessing, multithreading, or asyncio for this

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently struggling with how to approach this problem in Python 3.5+.

I have code that looks like this:

```
while True:
    do_process1() # run this synchronously
    do_process2() # don't wait on this to go to the next iteration but need to handle its completion
```

And in this instance, `do_process2()` takes a long time. I want `do_process2()` to run asynchronously so that the next iteration of the loop doesn't wait on `do_process2()` to complete.

From what I'm reading, I could use multithreading but with the GIL I don't see how I could "offload" `do_process2()` and continue execution of the next iteration.

It seems like multiprocessing would be a good fit here. With that being said, a lot of the examples I see out there are to *wait* on the subprocess to finish work. I don't want to do that, I want to keep executing the `while` loop.

Likewise, I want to be able to handle a callback from an asynchronous call to `do_process2()` so that I can handle the completion of that operation. I see that I could do that with a `Pool` object to `apply_async()`, but is that the best approach here?

What is the best approach here? And I'm using Python 3.5+, so wondering where asyncio would fit in all of this? I think like multi*threading*, I wouldn't have the gain I'm looking for on offloading and continuing work.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what's exactly happening inside `do_process2`, `multiprocessing` is the safe choice always(kind of a one size fit's all) since CPython has some documented issues with threads and the GIL, there are some event driven solutions but some of them have portability issues (I run a lot of Python code in Windows so portability is a deal breaker for me), finally there's `asyncio` which is kind of cool but as the notice says

> The asyncio package has been included in the standard library on a provisional basis. Backwards incompatible changes (up to and including removal of the module) may occur if deemed necessary by the core developers.

Comment: Thanks for the information! So does `asyncio` cater to the multithreading part of Python? Is it just another way?